# Using SSIS Task Exec SQL task with sp_send_mail

Tags: t-sql, ssis

I have a SSIS package which loops through a number of people then attaches a set of links to reports as attachments.

This all works fine with the Send mail task until I hit the 4,000 character limit :(

So I am trying to get this to work with the Execute SQL task, using sp_send_mail

I am trying something simple first but I cannot get it to work

Paramater : User::strPersonName
Direction : Input
Data Type : VarChar
Size : -1

SQL Statement =

```
DECLARE @bodytext AS VARCHAR(200)

SET @bodytext = 'Good Morning' + ?

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
    @profile_name = 'Shoop',
    @recipients = 'moonbase@hatstand.com',
    @subject = '1', 
    @body = @bodytext
```

I am getting the resultset not properly set up generic error

Any ideas? :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using sp_send_mail, you could still use the send mail task from SSIS. The 4000 character limit that I believe you are talking about, when populating your message, is on the expression, not on the variable itself. If you are using a MessageSourceType of variable in the send mail task, you can use the script task to build your message body (allowing you to create a string larger than 4000 characters).

Edit: Since the problem is with your attachments, I see one thing that could be a problem with the SQL for your Execute SQL task, according to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140355.aspx , you should use "?" as the parameter marker for ADO connections and "@" for ADO.NET, but it seems like you're using both.

As another alternative, here's a blog on how to use the script task and .NET to send your email. http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1753/sending-html-formatted-email-in-sql-server-using-the-ssis-script-task/

Comment: It does, but my problem is the attachments. When combining these they become over 4,000 chars (needs to be an expression) so I force them into 2 expressions based on a if statement. When concatenating them if fails (due to limit) so i thought that trying if via a SP would give me more flexibility?

Answer (score 0):

You shoudn't need a result set, but if you do make sure it is set correctly in the General tab in the SQL Task. From my understanding you are just passing in parameter data and not returning anything, so I think you have it set to *Single Row* instead of *None*.